# Easiest way to remove unwanted lines from a huge text file

Tags: macos, mac, text-manipulation

I have a large text file with a size of more than 30 megabytes. I want to remove all the lines which don't match some specific criteria, e.g. lines that don't have the string 'START'.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @MrStatic: MacOS

Answer (score 3):

If the pattern is really that simple, `grep -v` will work:

```
grep -v START bigfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

newfile.txt will have everything from bigfile.txt except lines with "START".

(In case it isn't obvious, this is something you'll do in Terminal or other command line tool)

Answer (score 2):

The original question asked how to remove the lines that didn't match a pattern. In other words, how to keep the lines that do match the pattern. Thus, no need for `-v`.

```
grep START infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Note that grep can use regular expressions to do much more powerful pattern matching.  The syntax is a bit obtuse though.

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU sed with the `-i` argument.

Comment: to make the answer a bit more .. verbose:  "sed -n -e '/START/p' inputfile". and maybe it is a good idea not to use -i while playing around with file altering commands, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -v START inputfile
```

should work. `grep` is standard on both MacOS and Linux/Unix, can be installed on MS Windows.

Option `-v` is for in*v*erting the match - only output lines that do not contain the pattern (the inverse of the usual grep behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Command Prompt (`help find` for options):

```
find /v "START" original_file.txt > new_file.txt
```

For Linux, OS X, etc. (`man grep` for options):

```
grep -v "START" original_file.txt > new_file.txt
```

For more complicated text matching `grep` offers a lot more functionality than `find`. If you are on Windows you can easily find a port of `grep` or you can use Windows' `findstr` instead of `find`.